# Start Java method at specific time

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I need that after I click a JButton a method will be called for example at 21:02:43.

Using Google I can find only delays but this is not what I need.

Comment: Cron job?  NT Scheduler?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

java.util.Timer has a schedule(TimerTask, Date) method. It does exactly this.

[Timer#schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date%29)

Added example:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // put code that needs to run here
    }
}, date);
```

Also lots of examples and information about timers here: [Timer and timertasks](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html)

Comment: Is it possibility to explain about this method?

Like, is I have method TIME and button  START to to set that when the button STRT pressed the method TIME will be called at 21:54:48 ??

Comment: I added and example of timers at a specific `Date`.

Comment: where i put specific time?

Comment: Note that it's unsafe to do any swing operations from this timer thread, you'd have to queue them to be run in the event dispatching thread instead.